# How to get file owner from network drive in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, file, file-io

How do I get **file owner from network drive** file in c# ?

I use this code:

```
string user = System.IO.File.GetAccessControl("filepath").GetOwner(typeof(System.Security.Principal.NTAccount)).ToString();
```

I get the file owner name if the domain of file owner is the same as my machine, but if domain is different than my machine then I get error that "**Some or all identity references could not be translated**."

Is it possible to do this?

Comment: are you sure the file isn't read-only?

Comment: yes, i have full access to file

Comment: that might be because current user is not a domain account... code is too short to decide.

Comment: yes , user is not a domain account. but what to do now if i want to retrieve username

Comment: Can you see the owner correctly if you browse to the file (right click on file -> properties -> security -> advanced -> owner) ?

Comment: This can happen with legacy users. A lot of time when you look at the path you will see the owner in explorer as "s-12332-43243-etc"

Answer (score 0):

```
string user = File.GetAccessControl("filepath").GetOwner(typeof(SecurityIdentifier)).Translate(typeof(NTAccount)).ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try below snippet,

```
string Owner = File.GetAccessControl("path").GetOwner(typeof(SecurityIdentifier)).Translate(typeof(NTAccount)).ToString();
```

You need to have access on it